# Component Links fields are not resolved once creating component using core services

Tags: core-service, web8, component

Once I preview a component created using core services then Component Links,Keywords and Images(via Media Manager) are not getting resolved.Once I open component change something and Checkin. Everything is ok now on preview.
Don't know why is this happening.
We are working on SDL Web 8.

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that XML you generated for content and metadata is ok? This looks like you generate invalid XML. When you open component it gets validated against schema and updated. Please compare XML before and after opening/closing component and check if it is different.

Comment: I could not see any change in XML generated for component before saving and after saving. I also tried using tridionClient.CoreServiceClient.SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdate(componentId, options) but not worked.

Comment: One more point to add CT for component is dynamic one.

Comment: Please show how you are invoking the Core Service. I guess the problem is in the `RenderMode`.

Comment: Hi @Rick Pannekoek                                                                                          I am using below code for creating component in CMS.                                                                            ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();                          compData = (ComponentData)tridionClient.CoreServiceClient.Create(componentData, readOptions);

Comment: This issue really baffles me. There must be something different before you change component via gui. To make sure that everything is the same, i suggest getting entire XML of component before and after and comparing it. Is it possible to add it here?